# Finding Unicode Characters in String Field with Regex in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a string field (comments) that contains a user id such as 'THOMASAN'. However, the string field is dynamic and can have a plethora of things written in it. But it always has the pattern 'UserID'. I am trying to use the  REGEXP_SUBSTR function in Oracle SQL to pull the name out.

I have tried REGEXP_SUBSTR(comments,'[A-Z]*') but it brings back null. In a string field how do I pull out this userid?

Comment: Could you show a sample comments data?

Comment: You're not telling the function you only want the user ID part. No time to properly answer but use the `subexpr` parameter of `regexp_substr()` and add a group around the part of the string you want to keep: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=59e6b44a3c05c2d91478c6d511066e48

Comment: Try `unistr('\F7FD') || '[[:alpha:]]+'`.

Comment: Something is wrong in your question. The Unicode character you show seems to be `\F7FD`. But that is not a valid Unicode character; the value F7FD is in the Private Use Area of Unicode, which means - by definition - that it is not assigned to any character. So, please elaborate. Working with Unicode in Oracle is not that difficult, but working with invalid Unicode values may be impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

For the specific unicode you mentioned ``

```
with cte as ( SELECT ' the left padding thomsan the right padding' comments FROM dual),
cte2 as (select ASCIISTR(upper(comments)) cmt from cte)

SELECT replace(regexp_substr( cmt, '\F7FD[A-Z]+', 1), 'F7FD','') userid from cte2;
```

Comment: The OP is asking specifically about difficulties with Unicode characters. The "THOMASAN" example was just that - and, the OP specifically mentioned that as something that works, while his more general case may include Unicode, and *that* doesn't work. Unless you can explain how your answer has anything to do with the question, and specifically with Unicode, I will have to come back and downvote this answer as "not helpful" (unless you choose voluntarily delete it yourself).

Comment: Next time, I will read the questions more carefully. what I understood is UserID will always be the pattern, and this special character  will be there as a prefix to UserID. Unless there are more  characters in the column value having the same pattern as UserID, my query should work for that specific character.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I was able to get the solution for my problem. I ended up with this REGEXP_SUBSTR(ASCIISTR(A.comments),'(|F7FD)([A-Z]*)_(CLOSE|COMPLETED)',1,1,'i',2)  as AGENT_USERID